# From Jax-ws client, how to invoke an OSB proxy which has ws policy Auth.xml enabled

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, jax-ws, osb

I have an OSB proxy service which uses predefined  ws policy Auth.xml. I want to invoke this proxy from a JAX-WS client service.

This is how my OSB proxy looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-fragment xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:env="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/env" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config" xmlns:con1="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/routing/config" xmlns:con2="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/config" xmlns:con3="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/transform/config" xmlns:con4="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/logging/config" xmlns:con5="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/security/config">
  <ser:coreEntry isProxy="true" isEnabled="true">
    <ser:security>
      <con5:inboundWss processWssHeader="false"/>
    </ser:security>
    <ser:binding type="SOAP" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="con:SoapBindingType" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config">
      <con:wsdl ref="../wsdls/TestServiceEndToEnd"/>
      <con:port>
        <con:name>TestServiceEndToEndEndpointPort</con:name>
        <con:namespace>/TestServiceEndToEnd</con:namespace>
      </con:port>
      <con:selector type="SOAP body"/>
    </ser:binding>
    <ser:monitoring isEnabled="false">
      <ser:aggregationInterval>10</ser:aggregationInterval>
      <ser:pipelineMonitoringLevel>Pipeline</ser:pipelineMonitoringLevel>
    </ser:monitoring>
    <ser:reporting>true</ser:reporting>
    <ser:logging isEnabled="true">
      <ser:logLevel>debug</ser:logLevel>
    </ser:logging>
    <ser:sla-alerting isEnabled="true">
      <ser:alertLevel>normal</ser:alertLevel>
    </ser:sla-alerting>
    <ser:pipeline-alerting isEnabled="true">
      <ser:alertLevel>normal</ser:alertLevel>
    </ser:pipeline-alerting>
    <ser:ws-policy>
      <ser:binding-mode>service-policy-bindings</ser:binding-mode>
      <ser:policies>
        <ser:operation name="testService">
          <ser:request-policy>
            <ser:predefined-policy>Auth.xml</ser:predefined-policy>
          </ser:request-policy>
        </ser:operation>
        <ser:operation name="updateService">
          <ser:request-policy>
            <ser:predefined-policy>Auth.xml</ser:predefined-policy>
          </ser:request-policy>
        </ser:operation>
      </ser:policies>
    </ser:ws-policy>
  </ser:coreEntry>
  <ser:endpointConfig>
    <tran:provider-id>http</tran:provider-id>
    <tran:inbound>true</tran:inbound>
    <tran:URI>
      <env:value>/proxy_services/testEndtoEnd_ps</env:value>
    </tran:URI>
    <tran:inbound-properties/>
    <tran:all-headers>false</tran:all-headers>
    <tran:provider-specific>
      <http:inbound-properties>
        <http:client-authentication xsi:type="http:HttpBasicAuthenticationType"/>
      </http:inbound-properties>
    </tran:provider-specific>
  </ser:endpointConfig>
  <ser:router>
    <con:flow></con:flow>
  </ser:router>
</xml-fragment>
```

From Jax-ws client, how to invoke an OSB proxy which has ws policy Auth.xml enabled.